# Please explain Get and Post in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.net . Can any one please explain what is the difference between Get and Post method in asp.Net.

Thanks
Pradeep.A

Comment: You can answer this yourself via searching. They are not specific to .NET, they are part of HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a sucker for detailed explanations, so [This Article](http://stevenclark.com.au/2008/01/12/get-vs-post-for-the-beginner/) and [This one](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html) do a good job with the details. But the short version is that GET passes data to the server encoded in the URL, and POST passes it in the body of the http request.

Comment: It's worth noting that they are not ASP.NET, or for that matter, .NET specific.

Comment: also worth nothing POST can pass data to the server via the URL as well.

Answer (score 2):

[The Wikipedia article on HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) would be a good place to start.

It's better to understand the underlying protocol before learning ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

"xelco52" very well explained. In addition "Get" and "Post" method is not .Net/ASP.Net specific. Other languages does the same also such as PHP.